# Get the file name without Extension in matlab

Tags: file, matlab, filenames

I want to get the image file name without the Extension in MATLAB.
I have Tried to use (fileparts )function as:

```
[pathstr, name, ext, versn] = fileparts(filename);
```

in this function the (filename) must be with complete Path in order to get the file name without extension in the the variable (name).

when I have just the file name like ('D10_11.jpg'), I get the following Error :

```
"Input must be a row vector of characters"
```

Please, if their is another function to solve this problem

Comment: your approach is false. The real question is why you are getting that error, why the variable filename is a cell array. If you do not understand this tomorrow you will have another very similar problem. The problem itself is trivial if you understand what cell arrays are.

Comment: @all: why are you upvoting such questions (see my comment above)???

Comment: @Mikhail: Apparently the SP was not aware of *cell arrays*, while facing an issue with the *fileparts* function. The issue was not trivial for him. Give him a chance to improve his understanding of MATLAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
>> filename = 'D10_11.jpg';
>> [pathstr,name,ext,versn] = fileparts(filename)

pathstr =

     ''

name =

D10_11

ext =

.jpg

versn =

     ''
```

You should check to make sure `filename` is actually what you think it is. The error suggests that it isn't just a row vector of characters like `'D10_11.jpg'`.

Comment: Note that you can reconstruct the file from the parts using `fullfile(pathstr,[name ext])`

Answer (score 14):

From your error message, I guess that the input could be a cell array, rather than a char array.

Thus, instead of

```
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename)
```

you'd have to write

```
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename{1})
```

Comment: thank you so much, I apply this function and the problem solved

Comment: @zenap: I'm glad it worked. Please consider accepting answers that you found helpful - it makes answerers happy and makes them more motivated to answer future questions.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the super late answer :(, but I was facing the same problem.
When I was searching for the answer I got the same question asked by someone else.
There is no problem with the query you have written, only problem I see here is you are missing the format of the filename location.

```
filename = 'C:\Users\Public\myfile.csv';

[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filename);
```

Output is

```
pathstr =
C:\Users\Public
name =
myfile
ext =
.csv
```